# Chart.Js ação mousehover

Tags: c#, chartjs, chart

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para aumentar o tamanho da "legenda" na ação mousehover da biblioteca Chart.Js.. eu li e não encontrei na documentação, alguém saberia?

segue imagem de como está atualmente:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que é ilegível o "normal" dentro do gráfico..

Comment: Você pode criar um fiddle?

Comment: Lendo a documentação mais a fundo encontrei o que queria, era a configuração relacionada ao ToolTip